# Convert sort from Python2 to Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, cmp

I've written a sort in Python2, I'm trying to convert it into Python3 which asks for a key and says no more cmp function is available :

```
test.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x[2],y[2]) or cmp(x[4], y[4]) or cmp(y[9], x[9]))
```

Any advices ?

Best regards,

Comment: At which point exactly are you stuck? Please edit your question accordingly refering to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Purely out of curiosity - what's that sort supposed to do? You're always going to end up with whatever the last comparison of elements 2, 4 or 9 aren't equal (either -1 or 1) or just 0 for equal... at the end... that seems almost randomly sorting to me. I have a feeling that's not a sort you wanted even if you could use it... are you sure what you're after as a key isn't just `key=lambda L: (L[2], L[4], L[9])` so you get some sort of "order" there?

Comment: There are two separate problems here: 1) Finding a replacement for the `cmp` function, and 2) Making the `sort` work with a `key=` function. Those two separate problems have two separate answers, so in the future please ask about each problem individually.

Comment: What's the structure of `test`? Eg, is it a list of lists, or a list of tuples?

Comment: test is created into a loop like that :

test.append((id, sexe, nom, prenom, date_naissance, telephone, sejour_id, etat, type, valeur))

Answer (score 5):

The official python 3 documentation [explains in this section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter) the proper way of converting this from python 2 to 3.

The original `cmp` function simply does something like

```
def cmp(x, y):
   if x == y:
       return 0
   elif x > y:
       return 1
   else:
       return -1
```

That is, it's equivalent to `sign(x-y)`, but also supports strings and other data types.

However, your problem is that the current function of `sort` doesn't work with a comparison function with two arguments, but with a single `key` function of one argument. Python provides `functools.cmp_to_key` to help you convert it, so, do something like

```
test.sort(key = functools.cmp_to_key(
    lambda x, y: cmp(x[2],y[2]) or cmp(x[4], y[4]) or cmp(y[9], x[9])
))
```